# Error 10060 while trying to connect an amazon mysql rds

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I created a `MYSQL Amazon RDS` instance and tried accessing it to through `MYSQL Workbench` from a windows machine.
But I'm getting an `10060` error whereas the `Amazon RDS` is publicly accessible.
I read some documentation on amazon forums, but I'm unable to understand how to set up `VPC`.
Any help will be appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Read the whole document again.  Pay attention to the connection part.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_GettingStarted.html

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This error is a result of the inbound connection rule set on your DB instance.

For each RDS database instance we create, there are Inbound & Outbound connection-security groups.

In AWS RDS console, under 'Databases', click on the 'DB Identifier' of your RDS instance. Then in the 'Security group rules' section, click on 'Inbound' type security group and edit the inbound rule to allow appropriate inbound connections.

You get 3 options here, under 'source' column:

- **Custom**
- **Anywhere** (Allows connections from any IP. Not recommended for production.)
- **My IP** (Automatically detects your machine's IP)

Comment: a missing route table route or a missing subnet association can also return the same error code.

Answer (score 10):

I missed enabling public accessibility while creating RDS. We can enable it later too in the modify section of RDS. Hope it helps someone.  [image: Please refer screenshot]

Comment: Thanks a lot, very small but f. important step.

Answer (score 5):

1st: add inbound rule.
-rds console
- instances
- details > Security groups(click link)
- EC2 Managment Console
- at the bottom of the page tab "inbound"
- edit > add rule
Choose Type: MYSQL/Aurora, Source: My ip
-save

2nd: if problem remainded try make sign out/sign in. It helped me two times contract.

Comment: Can you provide more information in your answer? What rule?

Comment: i explained about rules

Comment: I tried with all the above 3 posts, now I can able to connect maria db instance from my local

Answer (score 0):

For who had done all of the fix above and still fail to connect, you might want to dive deeper into sub-net's `Route table` and `Network ACL`

- Get your subnet's `Route table` and `Network ACL` of your RDS:
  Connectivity & security -> Networking -> Subnets -> select a subnet -> search for `Route table` and `Network ACL` of that subnet (You might have to repeat step for all other subnets)
- For `Route table`:

  - Create an `Internet gateway` [here](https://ap-southeast-2.console.aws.amazon.com/vpcconsole/home?#CreateInternetGateway:)
  - Select the route table of the subnet
  - Click `Edit routes`
  - Add a route (we can use 0.0.0.0/0 -> Internet gateway -> igw-(...) that we just create (this will open this subnet's gateway to entire world. USE WITH CAUTION))
  - Save
- For `Network ACL`:

  - Select the Network ACL of the subnet
  - click `Edit inbound rules` and `Edit outbound rules`
  - add desired IP address like with `Security groups`
  - Set `Rule number` lower than default denied * rule
  - Save