# Remote database connection error with Amazon RDS | Unable to connect (10060)

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am facing difficulty in establishing remote database connection (MySQL / MariaDB) to AWS-RDS. On the server side (AWS RDS) everything looks fine and even Inbound rules are set to accept My IP ( TCP Protocol over Port 3306). I am working on Windows machine so the error might be related to Windows Firewall. For this reason, I even added new Outbound and Inbound rule in Firewall Manager and set Remote Port to 3306. But still I end with below connection error:

```
The following error occurred:
Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxx.rds.amazonaws.com' (10060) QMYSQL: Unable to connect
```

Windows Firewall setting (similar for both Outbound & Inbound):

[image]

`Amazon RDS` is publicly accessible but still I am getting `10060` error. Is there something missing in Amazon (like in VPC) or is this caused by windows firewall?

I came across similar posts but those solutions didn't help. [AWS RDS connection error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37142701/error-10060-while-trying-to-connect-an-amazon-mysql-rds#:%7E:text=This%20error%20is%20a%20result,Identifier%27%20of%20your%20RDS%20instance.)

Can anyone please let me know what could be the issue and how to resolve it?

**Update**

After setting up VPC Flow logs to monitor the traffic, log messages are stored in S3 bucket with interval of 10mins. From 2 different logs, I could find:

```
version account-id interface-id srcaddr dstaddr srcport dstport protocol packets bytes start end action log-status
2       xx164      eni-08f88xxxx xx.xx.xxx.119 xxx.xx.2.17 34010 3306 6 5 260 1661944383 1661944424 REJECT OK
2       xx164      eni-08f88xxxx xx.xx.xxx.119 xx.xx.2.17 33953 3306 6 5 260 1661938359 1661938418 REJECT OK
```

The `srcaddr, dstaddr` and `dstport` is same in both cases but, `srcport` is different. Is this expected behavior? The `srcaddr` doesn't match with the IP addr set in security group (inbound rule). I don't understand which IP addr is taken as `srcaddr`.

Whereas doing `telnet rdsendpoint 3306` results in `Connecting To <rdsendpoint>...Could not open connection to the host, on port 3306: Connect failed`

Thanks in advance.

P.S: please let me know if any info is missing here.

Comment: did you check the server log files? it's hard to tell what the issue is with just one error message. do you have a more complete stacktrace of the error?  can you connect to it manually?

Comment: Hi @blurfus, thanks for the update. No I didn't have a look at server log files. Can you please let me know where this will be stored? I haven't come across this. Is it stored in AWS? I will update the OP with server logs

Comment: Try for testing purposes - open your Inbound Rules to all traffic. If that works, you know your issue is your inbound rules.

Comment: @blurfus I checked the log file (under Log & Events of database) but, it is empty. No error is logged.

Comment: @smac2020 Yes, I changed the inbound rule to All Traffic. But, still I have the same issue. So, I think it's not on AWS side.

Comment: You can check vpc flow logs. You need to enable them if you haven't already.

Comment: Hello @Riz I created a VPC flow log (tried both CloudWatch and S3 bucket options) but nothing is logged there. I am following this guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/flow-logs.html Any idea why nothing is logged?

Comment: At this point I would say your traffic doesn't reach at all to the vpc. If there are no errors in vpc flow logs creatin, it's 'impossible' that it doesn't log. Are you able to access it from inside the vpc? You can do a `telnet rdsendpoint 3306'. Also for vpc flow logs have you waited at least 10 min and then try?

Comment: Yes after waiting for 10 mins some logs are generated and stored in S3 bucket. I have updated my OP with log messages. Please have a look.

Comment: @Riz doing `telnet rdsendpoint 3306` results in `Connecting To <rdsendpoint>...Could not open connection to the host, on port 3306: Connect failed`

Comment: What are your NACL config?

Comment: @Riz I have default network ACL config i.e., Rule number 100, Protocol=ALL, Port Range=ALL. Similar to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-network-acls.html#default-network-acl

Comment: Lastly, is your DB in `available state`? If yes, then I am out of ideas. I would suggest to put maybe some screenshots of SG, subnet with route table, Public access in rds configuration. By the way, have you tried to do telnet or login from within the VPC from an EC2?

Comment: @Riz, yes it's in available state and publicly accessible. Should I setup ssh port forwarding? https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-mysql-ssh-workbench-connect-ec2/ 
Is this needed?

Comment: No, if your db is publicly available and is in public subnet with internet access, you do not need it. You can create an EC2 in the same subnet of DB(whcih is public) and try to access it via ssh. If you can't access it, then the issue lies with your routing.

Comment: @Riz after days of struggling, it was the VPN which was blocking connections. Now I could connect to rds. Thanks for your support :-)